combine VersionedTransaction[] into one for Actions/Blinks?
ActionPostResponsefrom @solana/actions accepts a "base64 encoded serialized transaction". I have an array of VersionedTransaction[] that I would like to compile as a single transaction for use as a Blink. Every method I have tried to combine these transactions results in a simulation revert, though I can see the correct transactions listed in the phantom preview. I also have no problem serializing a single VersionedTransaction from the array and getting a successful transaction preview and having the transaction land.
Is there a correct way to do this for Blinks?

what do these instructions do, are they dependent on each other? Have you checked that you are on the correct cluster? maybe that's why they are reverting?

@Jimii
I tried a lot of methods to combine that array, but ultimately gave up and rewrote the program to just make a single VersionedTransaction to start with. Not sure what wasn't working.
